# DB_Context with multiple tables in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created an API using .NET CORE and I have migrations to create a Movies table in a MySQL Database, The problem I have now is that I have multiple Tables for every user with the same schema of the table created with the migration, I need help on how to use the db context but change the table the data is gotten from in the API. The tableName is a variable.

The Movies Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BingeHUB_API.Models
{
    public class Movies
    {
        [Key]
        public int TMDB_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(70)]
        public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string MovieOverview { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string MovieOriginalLanguage { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime MovieReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public float MoviePopularity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public float MovieAverageVote { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool MovieForU18 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MovieImage { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MovieGenres { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MovieDownloadLink1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MovieDownloadLink2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MovieDownloadLink3 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string MovieStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Movies Migration

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace BingeHUB_API.Migrations
{
    public partial class moviesDbMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "movie",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    TMDB_ID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    MovieTitle = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", maxLength: 70, nullable: false),
                    MovieOverview = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", nullable: false),
                    MovieOriginalLanguage = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
                    MovieReleaseDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime(6)", nullable: false),
                    MoviePopularity = table.Column<float>(type: "float", maxLength: 5, nullable: false),
                    MovieAverageVote = table.Column<float>(type: "float", maxLength: 5, nullable: false),
                    MovieForU18 = table.Column<bool>(type: "tinyint(1)", nullable: false),
                    MovieImage = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", nullable: false),
                    MovieGenres = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", nullable: false),
                    MovieDownloadLink1 = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", nullable: false),
                    MovieDownloadLink2 = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", nullable: false),
                    MovieDownloadLink3 = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", nullable: false),
                    MovieStatus = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4", maxLength: 20, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_movie", x => x.TMDB_ID);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "movie");
        }
    }
}
```

The Db Context:

```
using BingeHUB_API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BingeHUB_API.Data
{
    public class BingeHUBApiContext: DbContext
    {
        public BingeHUBApiContext(DbContextOptions<BingeHUBApiContext> opt) : base(opt)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Movies> movie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Sql Repository:

```
using BingeHUB_API.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using BingeHUB_API.DTOs;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace BingeHUB_API.Data
{
    public class SQLCommanderRepo : ICommanderRepo
    {
        private readonly BingeHUBApiContext _context;
        private IConfiguration configuration;

        public SQLCommanderRepo(BingeHUBApiContext context, IConfiguration iconfig)
        {
            _context = context;
            configuration = iconfig;
        }

        void ICommanderRepo.addDownloadLink(Movies mv, string link)
        {
            //nothing
        }

        void ICommanderRepo.addMovie(Movies mv)
        {
            if (mv == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mv));
            }

            _context.movie.Add(mv);
        }

        void ICommanderRepo.deleteMovies(Movies mv)
        {
            if (mv == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mv));
            }

            _context.movie.Remove(mv);
        }

        IEnumerable<Movies> ICommanderRepo.GetAllMovies()
        {
            //the skip value is appended everytime the next button is clicked on a page and this shows the movies on the page;

            var movies = _context.movie.ToList();

            if (movies != null)
            {
                return movies;
            }

            return null;
        }

        IEnumerable<Movies> ICommanderRepo.GetMovieByTitle(string title)
        {
            var movies = _context.movie.Where(p => p.MovieTitle.Contains(title)).ToList();

            if (movies != null)
            {
                return movies;
            }

            return null;

        }

        Movies ICommanderRepo.GetMovieByID(int id)
        {
            var movies = _context.movie.FirstOrDefault(p => p.TMDB_ID == id);

            if (movies != null)
            {
                return movies;
            }

            return null;

        }

        bool ICommanderRepo.savechanges()
        {
            return (_context.SaveChanges() >= 0);
        }

        async Task<moviesCreateDTO> ICommanderRepo.GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            moviesCreateDTO TempMovie = new moviesCreateDTO();

            string kEy = configuration.GetValue<string>("TMDbKey:key");

            string Link = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+id+"?api_key="+kEy+"&language=en-US";
                        
            RestClient client = new RestClient(Link);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse restResponse = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            if (restResponse.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(restResponse.Content);

                var tempID = content["id"].Value<int>();
                var tempMovieTitle = content["original_title"].Value<string>();
                var tempMovieOverview = content["overview"].Value<string>();
                var tempMovieOriginalLanguage = content["original_language"].Value<string>();
                var tempMovieReleaseDate = content["release_date"].Value<DateTime>();
                var tempMoviePopularity = content["popularity"].Value<float>();
                var tempMovieAverageVote = content["vote_average"].Value<float>();
                var tempU18Decision = content["adult"].Value<string>();
                var tempMovieForU18 = false;
                var tempMovieStatus = content["status"].Value<string>();
                var tempMovieGenres = "";
                var Movieposterpath = content["poster_path"].Value<string>();
                var tempMovieImage = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + Movieposterpath;
                var tempDL = "TBA";


                if (tempU18Decision == "false")
                {
                    tempMovieForU18 = true;
                }

                var articles = content["genres"].Children();

                // this part gets the Id's from the json response and then concatonates them to a string genre
                foreach (var article in articles)
                {
                    tempMovieGenres = tempMovieGenres + article["name"].Value<string>() + ", ";
                }

                //this section is to get data from the json response and then save it to a new moviesCreateDTO;

                TempMovie = new moviesCreateDTO()
                {
                    TMDB_ID = tempID,
                    MovieTitle = tempMovieTitle,
                    MovieOverview = tempMovieOverview,
                    MovieOriginalLanguage = tempMovieOriginalLanguage,
                    MovieReleaseDate = tempMovieReleaseDate,
                    MoviePopularity = tempMoviePopularity,
                    MovieAverageVote = tempMovieAverageVote,
                    MovieForU18 = tempMovieForU18,
                    MovieImage = tempMovieImage,
                    MovieGenres = tempMovieGenres,
                    MovieDownloadLink1 = tempDL,
                    MovieDownloadLink2 = tempDL,
                    MovieDownloadLink3 = tempDL,
                    MovieStatus = tempMovieStatus,
                };
                                
                return TempMovie;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF Core provides two primary ways of keeping your EF Core model and database schema in sync. To choose between the two, decide whether your EF Core model or the database schema is the source of truth. If you want your EF Core model to be the source of truth, use Migrations. As you make changes to your EF Core model, this approach incrementally applies the corresponding schema changes to your database so that it remains compatible with your EF Core model. More detail information, see [Managing Database Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/).

Comment: @ZhiLv Okay, but if I use the database to create the schema does this then mean I can get a model for all the individual tables in the database or is it easier to just use a SQL and Query approach to edit the database.

Comment: I'm new to .NET so I don't understand a whole lot of it.

Comment: You could check the [Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx). The EF (core) provides two approaches: Code-First and Database-First. The development workflow in the code-first approach would be: Create or modify domain classes -> configure these domain classes using Fluent-API or data annotation attributes -> Create or update the database schema using automated migration or code-based migration. In the Database-First approach, you will create the database first, then based on the data tables to generate the relates classes.

Comment: "but if I use the database to create the schema does this then mean I can get a model for all the individual tables in the database" Yes, if you use database fist approach, it will generate the model base on the tables in the database.  The EF enables developers to work with data using objects of domain specific classes without focusing on the underlying database tables and columns. With the Entity Framework, developers can work at a higher level of abstraction when they deal with data and can create and maintain data-oriented applications with less code compared with traditional applications.